# Migrating Django from 2.2 to 3.2

Tags: python, django

I am migrating my application in Django 2.2 to version 3.2 and when passing the tests it gives me the following error that seems native to the framework. The application works perfectly, but the tests stopped working.

````
python manage.py test --keepdb


Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/proyecto/src/app/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 55, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 725, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 645, in setup_databases
    debug_sql=self.debug_sql, parallel=self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 183, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict['TEST'].get('SERIALIZE', True),
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 79, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 181, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 246, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 761, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_index(model, self.index)
  File "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 218, in add_index
    self.execute(index.create_sql(model, self, concurrently=concurrently), params=None)
TypeError: create_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'concurrently'```
````

Comment: i think you should check the documentation for Django 3.2, as things break when switching major versions.

Comment: There is no info about this.

Comment: It seems your installation of Django is somehow corrupted, try running `python -m pip install -U Django`.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You will run into a problem if change the Django version without updating the code. Read the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/upgrade-version/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue on the migration schema of your Postgresql schema, check the old schema migration and see if there is a new column or index, otherwise share we check it here

Share the schema.py on the mentioned path "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", we check line 218 which seems the index should be created concurrently and may have defined concurrently as a keyword which is failing to understand

Comment: Share the schema.py on the mentioned path  "/home/proyecto/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py",  we check line 218 which seems the index should be created concurrently and may have defined concurrently as a keyword which is failing to understand

Comment: You can see the code here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py

Comment: Hi,  the line 218 on the schema.py is a create_sql with create_index and i see there is a create_index_concurrently defined so use the index_concurrently since its the one throwing the error.

Comment: Hi, can you simulate the issue on django 2.2 and see if the same error occurs or not

Comment: In django 2.2 is working fine, it fails in Django >= 3.0